# The limit inferior for sequence of positive random variables where the WLLN does not hold

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose that $X_1,\dots, X_n$ are positive iid continuous random variables satisfying $E(X_i)=\infty$, and denote the sample average by $\bar{X}_n=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, then it is straightforward to show that $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ \bar{X}_n=\infty \quad\text{almost surely.}$$
This is somewhat of a *converse* Strong Law of Large Numbers (SLLN), although it only describes the limit superior. I am interested in what can be said of the limit inferior, which I think is required to show
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left[\bar{X}_n> 1+o(1)\right] = 1.
\end{align}
If I can show that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}\bar{X}_n$ diverges in some probabilistic sense, then I believe that Fatou's Lemma completes the rest.

1. Did I overlook something?
2. How do I show that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}\bar{X}_n$ diverges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under your assumptions it will hold that in fact $\lim_{n\to \infty} \bar{X}_n=\infty$ . Use truncation to get integrability and apply the LLL.

In case, that X can be infinite with positive probability you are done, since if one of the variable is infinite the arithmetic mean will be infinite.

Assume that $X$ is finite a.s.. Then, $X_i 1_{[0,N]} \to X_i$ for $N\to\infty$ monotonically, so $EX_i 1_{[0,N]} \to E X_i$. Finally,

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_i X_i \ge \frac{1}{n} \sum_i X_i 1_{[0,N]} \to_n E [X_i 1_{[0,N]}] \to_N E X_1 = \infty.$$